# How to write a linq query for this data structure

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class structure like this:

```
class Group
{
    public List<Group> SubGroups {get; set;}
    public List<Rule> Rules {get; set; }
}

class Rule
{
}
```

An instance example would be something like this:

```
Group 1
    SubGroup 1
        Rule 1
        Rule 2
    Rule 3
    Rule 5
Group 2
    SubGroup 2
        SubGroup 3
            Rule 7
            Rule 8
    Rule 6
```

Is there any way to get a list of all Rules using a LINQ query or do I have to create some recursive method?

Comment: var `rules = groups.SelectMany(x => x.Rules);`

Comment: @dustmouse This selects only the rules in the root group, not the ones in its subgroups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can't do it only with LINQ (without recursion). You can use helper for it. Like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Rule> GetRules(Group group) 
{
    foreach (var rule in group.Rules)
        yield return rule;
    if (group.SubGroups != null)
        foreach (var rule in group.SubGroups.SelectMany(g => GetRules(g)))
            yield return rule;
}
```

Or with more LINQ style:

```
public static IEnumerable<Rule> GetRules(Group group) 
{
     if (group.SubGroups != null)
         return group.Rules.Concat(group.SubGroups.SelectMany(g => GetRules(g)));
     else
         return group.Rules;
}
```

Comment: You'll need a null check on `group` for your LINQ solution